# Opposite of a requiem

Tags: expressions, word-usage, nouns, phrase-requests, vocabulary

The definition of a requiem is a song which plays on one's funeral. I was wondering, is there a word which means the opposite - a song which is used as a celebration of one's birth? Thank you!

Comment: Baptism songs? http://www.truevinemusic.com/baptism_songs.htm

Comment: I don't mean a genre, I mean a noun describing such a song; thanks, though!

Comment: @Josh61: Birth != baptism. If they were the same then the world would be 100% baptised (hence christian), including many animals...

Comment: Thanks for stating, Drew. What I am looking for is one word to describe a "birth celebration song". Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***Requiem*** 
(Requiem Roman Catholic Church)
a. A mass for a deceased person.
b. A musical composition for such a mass. ***Requiem*** 1300, from Latin requiem, accusative singular of requies "rest". ***It is the first word of the Mass for the Dead in the Latin liturgy***: *Requiem æternam dona eis, Domine* .... ["Grant them eternal rest, O Lord ...."]

Comment: Indeed, Josh - "a musical composition for such a mass". Is there a noun for a musical composition for a mass for a new-born person?

Comment: I have heard the term "birthsong" used once or twice, though the use was figurative.  And there is the problem that the term carries a lot of unrelated baggage, from midwife services to rap music.  But at least [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/birth-song) recognizes it.

Comment: I'm not so sure it makes sense that the opposite of a requiem would be for a birth.  A requiem mass isn't just for the dead; it's for the dead who were in the Church.  So some kind of a special mass, if there is such a thing, for a baptism (or confirmation) makes more sense since baptism and confirmation mark  one's entry into the body of Christ (the Church).

Comment: @A.Ellett - you are just right!!!

Comment: Okay, thanks, everyone! I'll just use something else.

Comment: Since the OP seems to have given up getting any help here and the question hasn't been answered, I suggest it be closed.

Comment: No one plays music at a birth. Everyone is too tired from staying up all night.

Comment: Mitch, doesn't have to be played literally at birth, just as a requiem isn't played literally the moment a person dies.

Answer (score 1):

*Aubade*   literally a Song for Dawn, is used figuratively.

Auden's lovely poem  which does what you say is called *Lullaby*:
 "Lay your sleeping head my love
  "Human on my faithless arm...